# Programming pattern for combining factory functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

Say you have a bunch of factory functions, each of which does two things:

1. Modify or add arguments to the initialization of a class
2. Does something with the class instance afterwards

E.g.

```
class Dog:
  def __init__(self, **very_many_kwargs):
    pass

def create_police_dog(department, **dog_kwargs):
  dog_kwargs['race'] = 'pitbull_terrier'
  dog = Dog(**dog_kwargs)
  police_academy = PoliceAcademy()
  police_academy.train(dog)
  return dog

def create_scary_dog(**dog_kwargs):
  dog_kwargs['teeth_size'] = 'MAX'
  dog_kwargs['eye_color'] = fetch_angry_eye_colors('https://dogs.com')
  dog = Dog(**dog_kwargs)
  dog.experience_unhappy_childhood()
  return dog
```

How to combine multiple of such functions in series?

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a "scary-police" dog? Then you can't without modifying these functions. I'd suggest using (multi)inheritance. So instead of functions, you'll have `class PoliceDog(Dog)`, `class ScaryDog(Dog)` and `class ScaryPoliceDog(ScaryDog, PoliceDog)`.

Comment: I'm aware of the necessity of rewriting the functions. Multiple inheritance is no solution because there are too many combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorators *almost* work but since you want your modifications to occur both before and after instantiation, they won't chain properly. Instead define a custom system of generic modifiers that can be chained together at creation time:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod                                                                  
                                                                                                     
class DogModifier(ABC):                                                                              
    @abstractmethod                                                                                  
    def mod_kwargs(self, **kwargs):                                                                  
        pass                                                                                         
                                                                                                     
    @abstractmethod                                                                                  
    def post_init(self, dog):                                                                        
        pass                                                                                         
                                                                                                     
class PoliceDog(DogModifier):                                                                        
    def __init__(self, department):                                                                  
        self._dept = department                                                                      
                                                                                                     
    def mod_kwargs(self, **kwargs):                                                                 
        kwargs['race'] = 'pitbull_terrier'                                                          
                                                                                                    
    def post_init(self, dog):                                                                       
        PoliceAcademy(self._dept).train(dog)                                                        
                                                                                                        
class ScaryDog(DogModifier):                                                                        
    def mod_kwargs(self, **kwargs):                                                                 
        kwargs['teeth_size'] = 'MAX'                                                                
        kwargs['eye_color'] = fetch_angry_eye_color('https://dogs.com')                             
                                                                                                    
    def post_init(self, dog):                                                                       
        dog.experience_unhappy_childhood()                                                          
                                                                                                    
def create_dog(*modifiers, **dog_kwargs):                                                               
    for m in modifiers:                                                                             
        m.mod_kwargs(**dog_kwargs)                                                                      
                                                                                                    
    dog = Dog(**dog_kwargs)                                                                         
                                                                                                    
    for m in modifiers:                                                                             
        m.post_init(dog)                                                                            
                                                                                                    
    return dog                                                                                      
                                                                                                    
# ...                                                                                               
                                                                                                    
police_dog = create_dog(PoliceDog('bomb squad'), kw1='a', kw2='b')                                  
scary_dog = create_dog(ScaryDog(), kw1='x', kw2='y')                                                
scary_police_dog = create_dog(PoliceDog('bomb squad'), ScaryDog(), kw1='z')
```

*code shown as example only - bugfixes left as an exercise for the reader

Comment: In `mod_kwargs`, `kwargs` need to be returned. I don't know why a copy of the dictionary is created but it is so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think my solution is the best and would be very interested in any other solutions. But here is my idea:

```
class DogFactory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dog_kwargs = {}
        self.dog_functions = []

    def scary(self):
        self.dog_kwargs['teeth_size'] = 'MAX'
        self.dog_kwargs['eye_color'] = fetch_angry_eye_colors('https://dogs.com')
        self.dog_functions.append(Dog.experience_unhappy_childhood)
        return self

    def police(self):
        self.dog_kwargs['race'] = 'pitbull_terrier'
        police_academy = PoliceAcademy()
        self.dog_functions.append(police_academy.train)
        return self


    def create(self):
        dog = Dog(**self.dog_kwargs)

        for f in self.dog_functions:
            f(dog)

        return dog


dog = DogFactory() \
        .scary() \
        .police() \
        .create()
```

Answer (score 0):

Each function should accept an *existing* instance of `Dog` and modify it, then return the modified instance. That way, you can simply compose the functions. (This is sort of a functional equivalent of the Builder pattern, though the example below is somewhat awkward and clunky.)

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, **very_many_kwargs):
        pass

def create_police_dog(dog, department):
    dog.race = 'pitbull_terrier'
    police_academy = PoliceAcademy()
    police_academy.train(dog)
    return dog

def create_scary_dog(dog):
    dog.teeth_size = 'MAX'
    dog.eye_color = fetch_angry_eye_colors('https://dogs.com')
    dog.experience_unhappy_childhood()
    return dog

scary_police_dog = create_scary_dog(
                     create_police_dog(
                       Dog(),
                       'vice'
                     )
                   )
```

---

Here is, I think, a more typical implementation of the Builder pattern.

```
class Dog:
    ...


class DogBuilder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.kwargs = {}
        self._train = False
        self._experience_unhappy_childhood = False

    def build(self):
        d = Dog(**self.kwargs)
        if self._train:
            PoliceAcademy().train(d)
        if self._experience_unhappy_childhood:
            d.experience_unhappy_childhood()
        return d

    def train(self):
        self._train = True

    def set_race(self, r):
        self.kwargs['race'] = r

    def experience_unhappy_childhood(self):
        self._experience_unhappy_childhood = True

    def make_police_dog(self, department):
        self.kwargs['department'] = department
        return self.set_race('pitbull_terrier').train()

    def make_scary_dog(self):
        return self.set_eye_color(fetch_angry_eye_colors('https://dogs.com')).
                    set_teeth_size('MAX').
                    experience_unhappy_childhood()


scary_police_dog = (DogBuilder()
                     .make_police_dog('vice')
                     .make_scary_dog()
                     .build()
```

---

Here's an approach using multiple inheritance (more specifically, *cooperative* multiple inheritance).

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, *, race, teeth_size='Min', eye_color=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.race = race
        self.eye_color = eye_color
        self.teeth_size = teeth_size


class PoliceDog(Dog):
    def __init__(self, *, department, **kwargs):
        kwargs['race'] = 'pitbull_terrier'
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        PoliceAcademy().train(self)


class ScaryDog(Dog):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['teeth_size'] = 'MAX'
        kwargs['eye_color'] = fetch_angry_eye_colors('https://dogs.com')
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.experience_unhappy_childhood()


class ScaryPoliceDog(PoliceDog, ScaryDog):
    pass


d = ScaryPoliceDog(department="vice")
```

Unless there is something specific about a scary police dog that doesn't apply to an ordinary police dog or scary dog, nothing special needs to be done in `ScaryPoliceDog`. It's all handled via delegation using `super`.

In particular:

1. The MRO for `ScaryPoliceDog` is `PoliceDog`, `ScaryDog`, `Dog`, `object`. The `__init__` method for each will be called in turn.
2. `super()` in `PoliceDog` does *not* refer to `Dog`; it refers to `ScaryDog`, because that's the class following `PoliceDog` in the MRO.
3. `ScaryPoliceDog` does not need to specify a race. Although that field is required by `Dog`, it will be supplied by `PoliceDog`, as `PoliceDog.__init__` will be called first.